# Embed an image in Outlook 2010 when send email with ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a question: it is possible to embed somehow an image in mail message without let user to click automatic download in Outlook ?

I wrote simple C# code:

```
string message = "<p><img src='test1.jpg' />";
SendEmail( "to@test.com", "from@test.com", "Subject", message );
```

In my Outlook, the image is hidden and I have to click on Automatic download images.

I tried also to write image source as base64 code

```
string message = "<p><img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAR8AAAA8CA...' />";
SendEmail( "to@test.com", "from@test.com", "Subject", message );
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Even if you embed the image into the mail I think that users could always configure Outlook to block images.

Comment: Agree but is user's choice to block or not. But I want to display somehow that image without clicking on automatic download pictures...If is not possible then I'll delete this question.

Comment: Don't delete your question. If someone else wants to know the answer, he may find it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done - you have to embed images as linked resource. Following code replaces img tags with their equivalents, downloads images on server side and attaches them as linked resource to email.

```
public void Email(string htmlBody, string emailSubject) {
  var mailMessage = new MailMessage("from@company.com", "to@company.com");
  mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
  mailMessage.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  mailMessage.Body = htmlBody;
  mailMessage.Subject = emailSubject;
  // embedd images
  var imageUrls = new List<EmailImage>();
  var regexImg = new Regex(@"<img[^>]+>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  var regexSrc = new Regex(@"src=[""](?<url>[^""]+)[""]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  mailMessage.Body = regexImg.Replace(mailMessage.Body, (matchImg) => {
    var value = regexSrc.Replace(matchImg.Value, (matchSrc) => {
      string url = matchSrc.Groups["url"].Value;
      var image = imageUrls.Where(i => string.Compare(i.Url, url, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0).FirstOrDefault();
      if (image == null) {
        image = new EmailImage { Url = url, MailID = Convert.ToString(imageUrls.Count) };
        imageUrls.Add(image);
      }
      return string.Format(@"src=""cid:{0}""", image.MailID);
    });
    return value;
  });

  if (imageUrls.Count > 0) {
    var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailMessage.Body, null, "text/html");
    for (int i = 0; i < imageUrls.Count; i++) {
      var request = WebRequest.Create(imageUrls[i].Url);
      var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
      var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
      var memoryStream = new MemoryStream((int)response.ContentLength);
      CopyStream(stream, memoryStream);
      memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      var imageLink = new LinkedResource(memoryStream, GetContentType(response.ContentType, imageUrls[i].Url));
      imageLink.ContentId = imageUrls[i].MailID;
      imageLink.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
      htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imageLink);
    }
    mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
  }

  SmtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

Support methods/classes:

```
private void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output) {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
  int read;
  while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
    output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
  }
}

private string GetContentType(string serverContentType, string imageUrl) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("imageUrl");

  ImageMimeType mimeType;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverContentType)) {
    serverContentType = serverContentType.ToLowerInvariant();
    mimeType = ImageMimeType.MimeTypes.Where(m => m.MimeType == serverContentType).FirstOrDefault();
    if (mimeType != null) {
      return mimeType.MimeType;
    }
  }

  string extension = Path.GetExtension(imageUrl).ToLowerInvariant();
  mimeType = ImageMimeType.MimeTypes.Where(m => m.FileExtension == extension).FirstOrDefault();
  if (mimeType != null) {
    return mimeType.MimeType;
  }
  return "application/octet-stream";
}


private class EmailImage {
  public string Url { get; set; }
  public string MailID { get; set; }
}


private class ImageMimeType {
  public string FileExtension { get; private set; }
  public string MimeType { get; private set; }
  public static List<ImageMimeType> MimeTypes = new List<ImageMimeType> {
    new ImageMimeType { FileExtension = ".png", MimeType = "image/png"},
    new ImageMimeType { FileExtension = ".jpe", MimeType = "image/jpeg" },
    new ImageMimeType { FileExtension = ".jpeg", MimeType = "image/jpeg" },
    new ImageMimeType { FileExtension = ".jpg", MimeType = "image/jpeg" },
    new ImageMimeType { FileExtension = ".gif", MimeType = "image/gif" },
    new ImageMimeType { FileExtension = ".bmp", MimeType = "image/bmp" }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image is simple (i.e. not many colors, simple geometry) you can convert it into an HTML table, and then embed it in an HTML e-mail. You can use [this](http://img2html.odednoam.com/) open source tool to do the conversion.